# A fruit that electrically shocks you

Tags: biology, evolution, electricity

I want my world to contain a fruit that electrically shocks you to the point where it's painful, whenever you bite into it. Now, there are many organisms in nature that produce sensations similar to electricity (jellyfish, electric daisy, etc.) but I want my fruit to *actually* shock you. What would have to happen for this to be possible, and what might be different in a world where such a fruit exists? Some ideas:

- The fruit could have evolved electrocution as a defense mechanism, similar to how cacti are prickly or peppers are spicy.
- Could this fruit be used culinarily? Maybe you can make a dish with this fruit in small quantities to have a tingly effect.
- If this fruit is essentially a natural battery, you could produce fires much easier than by rubbing sticks together. How might this impact society? Could this fruit start fires spontaneously?
- Would this fruit have lead to earlier development of electricity and related technologies?

Comment: It would be largely counterproductive. Seeds are how a plant propagates; fruit is simply a means of attracting animals to disperse those seeds. having vectors chased off by electric shocks is not a positive evolutionary trait. In the case of peppers, the really hot ones grow on small plants; its evolutionarily positive to chase off animals that could simply eat the whole plant, but not very good for propagation, which is why they have many hard, small seeds to maximise their distribution off the first mouthful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding Riley. The simple way to go about this would instead be to ask: if there anything that **prevents** or makes it **unlikely** that such a plant could evolve? If you cannot find any such reason then you can just go ahead. Also, please limit yourself to one question per post. It is better to split a post such as yours up into several with one question per post. Short answer: can it be used as food? Well if it evolved this defence, obviously some species thinks it is good to eat. Is it a battery? Sort of it seems. Can it start a fire spontaneously? Probably.

Comment: "Earlier development"? Earlier than what?

Comment: @MichaelK I thought my question "What would have to happen for this to be possible?" addresses your concern of what makes it **unlikely**. I intended for my bulleted list to serve more as just giving some ideas. I don't expect each of those bullets to be answered in depth, so I think it's appropriate to leave it all in one question. By "earlier development" I just meant earlier than our actual world. For example, in my world maybe somewhat primitive societies figured out how to use electricity as an energy source.

Comment: @MichaelK Also, I felt that leaving out the bulleted list would give the impression that I hadn't put much thought into my idea. I know that in other stack exchange communities at least, simply asking a question without demonstrating effort is frowned upon.

Comment: I would suggest that a chemical in the fruit reacts with a chemical in human saliva to produce electricity. However only 0.5% isn't water, so any charge produced wouldn't be very strong and human saliva varies alot. Well atleast in real life, you can do whatever you want in a story

Comment: A very similar thing is used as 'crazy NPC flavor text' in Everquest II. That is, you address a certain gnome, and he says, "If fruit were explosive, it would be a delicious new source of energy."

Comment: @nzaman Are you sure about that, I was under the impression that spicy fruits were trying to dissuade mammals (who are affected by spice) but attact birds (who are not affected by spice)  ref: http://scienceblogs.com/clock/2006/07/21/hot-peppers-why-are-they-hot/

Comment: @nzaman there is no requirement that seeds must be distributed by animals, and there's also no requirement that all animals must be repulsed by a mild electric shock.

Comment: Electrocution is a poor defense mechanism for a plant. It works for electric eels because it stuns/surprises predators long enough for the eel to escape - fruit and fruit trees, however, cannot escape. A fruit couldn't provide a sustained electrical charge, or even one long enough to cause damage (even eels can't shock long enough to stop a human heart), so once you get past the first jolt it's safe to eat (which should also answer your culinary question). Anything more than that is so handwavy you can make up whatever you like.

Comment: we all agree that fruit must contain traces of water however small, presence of electricity adds energy to the water and boils it away which is bad for the fruits! I can explain the presence of electricity but considering the amount of energy needed by the plant I can guarantee you will be disappointed...

Comment: If it exists in your world, it had better be called the black-current. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Xenocacia That or the zapple.

Comment: As an example in fiction, the [Electric Banana](http://toriko.wikia.com/wiki/Electric_Banana) has narcotic properties which drive people to eat it.

Comment: Not quite the same, but pineapples secrete enzymes which digest the skin in your mouth, which is why it sometimes hurts your mouth when you eat pineapples.

Comment: @Riley You have an alien world, with alien biology, and alien evolution. This means that **anything** that is not outright limited by the laws of physics, is possible. Do not lock yourself into the "Like Our World, Only Slightly Different"-trap because that is not how an alien world will be.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Didn't know about the birds, but it makes sense. Birds are far less likely to eat the whole plant than mammal herbivores

Comment: @nzaman I believe in the case of chillies its that the mammals destroy the seeds (defeating the object) but the birds eat them whole. If the aim was to protect the plant itself then why not just make the plant spicy but not the fruits

Comment: @nzaman not necessarily, say that the stuff in the fruit needs to grow mature before it can be eaten or the seed is wasted no matter which animal poops it out. Then something needs to protect it for it to allow the stuff inside to reach fruitful state. Electricity can be that protection.

Comment: Hum, since when did _electrocution_ stop describing _electric execution_ and just come to mean _electric shock_?

Comment: Just to add my opinion to the whole pepper fruit / bird thing, I had heard that the real benefit that the plant got was that a bird is more likely to carry the seeds far away before... dropping... them (moving a lot quicker and not being inhibited by things like rivers, canyons and cliffs), thus increasing the range that a single plant can spread its seeds.

Comment: @RichardTingle, many pepper plant as "poisonous" root and sap. I can't find any reference of it, but it's a common soup to cure cheating husband.

Comment: Electrocute means to *kill* or *execute* by electrical means. Is that what you mean, or do you mean electric shock?

Comment: @JYelton I meant electric shocks. I'll change the question

Comment: @pipe I believe electrocute has meant to be killed or severely injured by electricity either deliberately or accidentally for some time. Ref: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73880/if-someone-is-electrocuted-do-they-have-to-die-or-can-they-just-be-injured

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How it would produce electricity? Most likely, the same way [electrical eels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_organ_(biology)) do, I suppose - a mesh of long cells, that get electric potential due to work of [ion channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_channel). They would be activated by some activator being released in fruit when it is damaged, the same way damage of the endothelium causes [coagulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coagulation#Regulators).

About evolution of such plant - it could start from plant signalling to insects via electric field(many insects react to them) and later signalling cells would change the purpose the same way nerves of electrical eel became weapon(it kills its victims with thought :) ). Another interesting way of using electricity - electrolysis of hydrogen for flying seeds(though hydrogen can be more efficiently generated via usual organic reactions).

// fruit is simply a means of attracting animals to disperse those seeds. having vectors chased off by electric shocks is not a positive evolutionary trait.

One animal may eat the plum, swallows the seed, and excrete it far away later, surrounded in fertilizer. Another one may eat the juicy part and spit out the seed nearby. Obviously, plant would prefer the first one. So if fruit is swallowed and slowly digested it would not produce electric shock, if it is eaten by parts, it would shock the animal.

Comment: Fruit is a means to attract the *right* animals to disperse the seeds.  Consider hot peppers: a mammal eating the fruit will grind up and digest the seeds.  Birds, on the other hand, have low-efficiency digestive systems that leave the seeds intact and are ideal for dispersing seeds.  Peppers produce capsaicin, which discourages mammals from eating the fruit, but which birds can't taste.  By the same token, an electric fruit might be trying to get a specific animal to disperse its seeds.

Answer (score 15):

Building off of ash, which is a nice idea, the charge is what draws the 'animals' to the fruit. They have a corresponding organ to harvest that energy. They use the charge, just as we use the sugar in our fruits.

Comment: Still not a fruit you necessarily want to eat but possibly more palatable than my option.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I suppose if riley wants it to be unpleasant and shocking, then the animals must be eating it despite it's shock, because enough of the charge is harvested somehow.

Comment: I think this answer is reasonable. There could be a few species that harvest the electricity while it's painful to most other animals.

Comment: I'm watching squirrels gather acorns.  Acorns are full of tannin, a poison that squirrels have developed a resistance to.  Acorns are a seed, so while it would seem the squirrels are parasitic, the truth is that squirrels often "forget" where they have hidden them, causing a chance for another tree to grow.  Tannin is used to preserve leather, so it has the ability to be used for more than than the tree "intended" it to be used for (undeveloped fruits contain tannin as a way to stop animals from eating them.  When the seed is ready, the tannin is replaced by sugar)

Comment: To really get this to evolve (why only be eaten by animals that can harvest charge? why narrow the range of possible seed distributors?), you need something behaviorally in these electricity-harvesting animals that is essential, or at least beneficial, in the successful propagation of these plants. Contrarily, the electricity could deter pests that would damage or destroy the seeds of the fruit.

Comment: Puts a whole new meaning to battery hens.

Answer (score 12):

"Electrocution" means "electrifying something until it dies".

So, why would a plant do this? Because it's a carnivorous plant that feeds on them. The fruit are just a lure. As for how, well, I think you hit on it when you mentioned the electrical eel.

Comment: I have something similar in a desert-world universe except they're just horribly toxic, it's easier.

Comment: I was thinking that the fruit would just be painful to eat, but I guess what hurts a large animal could kill smaller animals. Maybe "electrifying" was the right word, instead of "electrocution"

Answer (score 10):

Fruit is designed to *attract* not repel predation, as such an electric charge is generally counterproductive.

There may however be a reasonable explanation for an electric "fruit" of sorts; consider that the "fruit" is not a sweet fruit that we would tend to think of when we hear the word but rather a body containing seeds like a pine cone that is sealed against the elements until such time as the weather is right to disperse the seeds and have them germinate. Such cones often rely on fire in the modern world but an electric charge could serve a similar purpose or could in fact be an ignition source for a fire dependent species. Cones could build up a friction charge from the wind and/or the rubbing of cones against each other, you would not want to touch a charged cone. This is not a "fruit" that would not be used for food nor, at least in my opinion, would another example of biological electricity advance the development of the science any. I in fact would expect that this would have little overall impact on the world we know since such trees would live within existing burn dependent forest ecosystems.

Comment: I don't think this satisfies what I was going for. Wouldn't it shock you just once, when you touch it? I wanted a fruit that is painful while you're eating it.

Comment: I can't think of any reason a fruit you'd want to eat would be electric, it serves no useful purpose, sorry I shall edit the answer to better reflect that fact.

Comment: What I'm saying is that eating the fruit should be painful. I'm not saying that creatures want to eat it. My concern is that if the fruit only builds up a friction charge, then simply touching it would discharge it, making it safe to eat. But I'm asking about the possibility of a fruit that perpetually shocks you while you're eating it.

Comment: @Riley I don't think that's workable, the only known processes for the biological production of electricity rely on a very finely tuned pieces of physical anatomy, that can't survive being cut, possibly cooked, and eaten, you'd trash the mechanism for charge production before it ever got to the diner.

Comment: Well, I'd still consider the case that it shocks you if you eat it straight off the tree, but preparing it will eliminate the shocking mechanism. I think this case could make sense. Maybe eating it off the tree is disadvantageous because the seeds aren't developed yet.

Comment: @Riley That is certainly a workable argument, in that case it may or may not shock the person trying to pick it as well, picking these may in fact be a highly skilled and dangerous career.

Comment: Not all fruits want to be eaten. Only the ones that rely on animals to transport them try to be attractive. Cocoa beans for example have developed a bitter taste in order to stop animals from eating them.

Comment: @Riley does it have to be a fruit? A root that electrifies predators makes much more sense. Think like an onion, or a ginger root but with electricity!

Comment: @ClangorousChimera But the fruit around those bitter beans is sweet, or at least nutritious, I understand it's actually pretty bland with Cacao.

Comment: @Loupax That's a cool idea, I'm so stealing that for my Steel Trees World.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how the fruit could do it:

A charge is gradually accumulated on the inside (via ion channels in the usual method).  An insulating layer of avocado-like fat wraps this inner pulp.  The thin outside layer accumulates the opposite charge.

On biting into this fruit, the biting apparatus of the eater completes the circuit.  The outer and inner layers equilibrate, with charge coursing along the mandible or mouthparts of the fruigvore.

One fruit could deliver one shock.  That might be enough to kill an insect or small animal.  After the frugivore ceases its effort (and falls off). the fruit might be able to heal and regenerate charge, just as a fruit which is pecked or otherwise cut while still on the tree can sometimes repair the damage given time.

Fruits dissuade frugivores all the time. Especially to be dissuaded are insect frugivores, who spoil the fruit and are too small to disperse seeds.   If the fruit is eaten before the seed is ready then the whole seed dispersal scheme is kaput. Unripe fruits are bitter tasting to us or unpalatably sour, and contain proteases and other enzymes intended to disrupt the digestion of fruigvores intended to eat them before they are ripe.  These substances are why one must cook green tomatoes.  Fruits also want to dissuade the wrong types of frugivores - hot peppers being a prime example.  Peppers do want to be eaten, but by birds, not mice.  Mice will chew up the seeds but birds will pass them.

A fruit like this will maintain a charge only while on the tree.  Just as a ripe fruit will turn off proteases and other antifrugivore mechanisms, when it wants to be eaten this electric fruit will cease to maintain its charge.  Once off the plant, the energy source (from the leaves) used to maintain the charge differential is gone, and the charge difference will slowly wane.  An electric fruit might use a shock like this to make sure it is eaten only after falling on the ground (by something like a coati who will disperse the seeds).

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing a lot of people saying that the point of a fruit is to attract animals to eat it... but, all the plant really needs is for at least **one** animal to be able to eat it. Take a look at the manchineel tree. It's one of the deadliest plants alive, with sap that can damage the paint on cars. Standing under it during a rain will cause your skin to blister, and burning the tree causes smoke that can burn your eyes... so, needless to say, ingesting its apples is a pretty bad idea.

Unless you're a black-spined iguana, which eats the apples *and* lives in the boughs.

It's a tenuous relationship, of course--if anything happens to the iguana, the tree is done for--but as long as it holds, the machineel tree is nearly invincible to attack from herbivores and parasites, and the iguana has a reliable food source with no competition and a safe place to live.

All you need is at least one animal with a mouth that conducts electricity poorly (or perhaps is smart enough to coat its mouth in something that is first), and voila, you've got your seed dispersal!

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't be an edible fruit, so it would use another form of seed dispersal. I am thinking a fruit that when it pops either because it matured or because something bit it shoots a multitude of small seeds at significant force. The seeds will when be carried by the wind. So I am guessing the normal trigger would be wind making the plant and the fruit sway.

How is this related to electricity?

[Triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) creates voltage on separating surfaces. When the seeds are shot from the fruit they are obviously separating from it. If the connecting surfaces of the seeds and the fruit are in the opposite ends of the triboelectric series, both will acquire electric charge. On the fruit this would likely be irrelevant, but on the seeds the acquired charge would force the seeds apart from each other and spread the long fibers on their surface for maximal surface area. Both of which the plant wants.

I doubt this is exactly what you want, but eating a fruit like this **would** hurt and if the seeds have high ratio of surface area to mass, as they reasonably would, much of the pain **would** be from electric shock inside your moist and sensitive mouth.

Answer (score 4):

You could easily have a scenario where the plant and some animal evolved together such that only this particular animal can safely consume the fruit. This facilitates dispersal of the seeds by a specific animal. The term is coevolution, and is fairly common in nature. In terms of a mechanism by which the electricity is generated, you could look to something like an electric eel, but I would consider instead [lemon batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery) for inspiration, where there's a chemical reaction between the juice of the fruit and electrodes. In your case, you could have some compound in the juice of your fruit that reacts with something commonly found in mouths of most species species. Perhaps a compound in saliva. Then, the animal that coevolved with the plant can have something different about it's saliva that inhibits the reaction, keeping it from getting shocked.

In terms of culinary uses, the intensity of the shock can be based on how much you dilute the juice you extract from the fruit. Dilute the juice enough, you just get a tingly sensation.

Answer (score 3):

Re: the first part of Ash's answer (that I can't reply to) "Fruit is designed to attract not repel predation, as such an electric charge is generally counterproductive."

Capsaicin-containing fruits are an adaptation that repels mammals, who feel its effects and are less capable of spreading seeds after consumption, but not birds, who don't feel its effects and are more capable of properly spreading the seeds ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin#Natural_function)). If your world also features a species or taxon that is both better adapted to spreading your fruit's seeds and also somehow less vulnerable to being electrocuted while eating it, that would make evolutionary sense.

Answer (score 3):

Many have pointed out that evolving electrocution powers on a fruit is counterproductive. So instead, what if...

## The delicious but dangerous growth isn't a fruit

From its formation, this world has had terrible weather conditions. Sunlight is very limited in large parts of the world, and as such, the few lifeforms that have managed to evolve have done so by inventing methods for dealing with the lack of sunlight. Some did so by storing energy gained from the sun, perhaps by raising load-bearing branches on the uncommon clear day and lowering them to release that energy for survival the rest of the time, or by storing the energy mechanically or chemically.

This organism's solution was different.

[Some plants are rich in zinc](https://www.globalhealingcenter.com/natural-health/foods-high-in-zinc/), and [some plants are rich in copper](https://draxe.com/top-10-copper-rich-foods/). These are provided by the soil, which is in turn fertilized by dead organic matter. Your plant in question gathers both and applies them to an electrolyte-rich growth, [just like a lemon battery.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery)

This electrolyte-rich growth differs from a fruit in that it does not contain seeds. The growth is divided into chambers by organically-produced wax, which serves as an insulator and allows the chambers to be combined in series to produce a greater voltage. Biting into the growth provides a conductive connection between two chambers at differing potentials, resulting in electric current passing through the victim's body. Probably not enough to be fatal to any but the weakest of species, but likely enough to cause noticeable discomfort.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of why the tree would do this, consider the chili pepper, the capsasin discourages large mammals that can digest their seeds so only birds (who are not affected) will eat them and spread their seeds. 
Now imagine your tree produces a strong charge in its fruit, birds would be unaffected but and large animal standing on the ground that tried to eat the fruit would get a shock because it completes a circuit with the ground. Now we have a reason your plant has such weird fruit it wants birds to eat it but not large animals becasue they can break down their seeds and birds can't.

As for how it does this this is not too hard [cell membranes can make good capacitors](http://stg.rutgers.edu/ourpubs/Golowasch_Nadim_2015_Encyc_Comp_Neuro.pdf), your plant just needs to stack an incredible amount of cell membranes together and build up a charge potential across them. Also consider that teeth are very electrosensitive (it has to do with how teeth first evolved), so this will work doubly well on most mammals, it may not even need that strong of a charge.

this also means that once the fruit has discharged it will take time to build up a charge again, so a clever human could figure out how to harvest them safely.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With some citrus fruits, such as a lemon, one can build a battery by inserting metal strips. The citric acid in the lemon causes corrosion of the metals, generating an electric current.

It is possible that a plant could extract the appropriate minerals from the soil, and transport them to the fruit, where they could be contained in some form of neutral fluid, until some creature bites into the fruit, bringing the acid into contact with the minerals, and electricity is generated.

With numerous containers of minerals, the fruit should be capable of producing several charges for multiple bites. It wouldn't take a lot of electricity to do the job - most animals have sensitive mouths, where even a mild electric charge will be extremely unpleasant.

Answer (score 3):

**It's not just the fruit itself, it's also the seed!**

As the fruit decays, juice vesicles (like those in a citrus fruit) gradually release chemicals that produce a very mild chemo-electric current which triggers and supports the germination of the seed. When the fruit first falls, the impact with the ground releases a larger jolt needed to penetrate the somewhat-insulated seed coat. When the seed receives this jolt, not only does it start germinating, but it also releases *it's own* jolt to help break down the insulating seed coat, which also helps the fruit to produce more chemo-electricity, in a positive feedback loop.

**Chomp**

When an animal comes and takes an abrupt, huge bit out of the fruit (particularly if it's fresh fruit from a tree, which isn't yet triggered by a ground impact), it not only produces an abnormally large fruit-shock, but also triggers a similarly large response shock from the seed (which triggers more from the fruit, which triggers more from the seed, etc. etc. etc.). This results in the seed itself popping (like a cross between a popcorn kernel and a Galaxy Note 7's battery) and the crispification of a would-be frugivore.

**FOOD**

However, if the seed is *carefully* removed, the fruit itself can be used for rather stimulating cuisine! Electric fruit salads, "Jolt Juice", and many other novel dishes can be made. The intensity of a fresh fruit's current might be unappealing, but you can let it ripen a bit and lose some of its potential. Cultures that regularly eat it tend to have special baskets for carrying and storing them so they can be handled safely, and people with children or pets must be careful to keep the fruits out of reach.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Harris Weinstein.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of people have addressed the thoughts on why a plant would want to do this.  Lets look at a possibility of How it could be a bug zapper.

Design the Fruit to have some layers, much like a [Leyden Jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar).  A Leyden Jar is essentially a primitive capacitor. Some of them can hold a respectable charge (I remember a high school physics teacher swear loudly and involuntarily drop one when it discharged into his hand)

A conductive outer skin, a layer of non-conductive pith and a conductive inner material and stem.  Static would build up from the environment builds in the fruit. The undesirable bird or bug gets too close, landing on or near the stem.  He provides a ground for the fruit to discharge into and zap, no more bug or bird.

The fruit will ground and discharge when the fall out of the trees, and then bears or whatever eat the fruit and spread the seeds around.

A totally organic bug zapper, I like it.  I hate bugs

Answer (score 1):

A good explanation is not FRUIT that electrocutes you, but some other part of the plant (stems?) that would.  Their purpose is to keep the yummy fruit from being eaten before it was mature enough to propagate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in an imaginary world that you would like a "fruit" that electrify whoever bites it (whether you wanna use it as a bait for later eating or just some random ideas), would be fun to "model it" as:

- A plant that **absorbs** the electricity in the atmosphere and put it in its fruits to act as a bomb (**electricity bomb**) to stun their prey before eating it or w/e you want to do. You could check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_electricity) or Google Search in order to get more detailed data related to the behaviour or the "Electricity in the Air".

If you also say that the stun of the fruit, just like the spice, could be something that people will be looking for in order to get **feel better** or add different tastes to their foods, that could reinforce the argument.

Is interesting to remind you, guys, **that when you eat spicy food**, you are actually burning your tongue/mouth so the body produces endorphin to  make you feel better. I quote [this article](http://www.medicaldaily.com/pass-spicy-food-4-ways-get-high-without-any-drugs-whatsoever-323588), that backup that argument:

> Chili peppers in particular contain high levels of the substance
>   capsaicin, which causes the burning sensation in spicy food. The
>   chemical has been proven before to work as a topical painkiller for
>   arthritis, and also forces the brain to release endorphins. “The
>   endorphins work to block the heat,” Paul Bosland, cofounder and
>   director of New Mexico State University’s Chile Pepper Institute, told
>   ABC News in 2012. “The body produces them in response to the heat,
>   which it senses as pain.”

So, based on that, you could also say that eating this fruit would have the same effect in human/animal body.

I dont think that I need to reinforce the idea of the plant need to survive and that why it shouldn't hurt the human/animal just because there are so many carnivorous plants in the world that, one plant that actually can stun you before **eating you** doesn't look **that scary** or crazy.

Comment: Welcome to the site Fingolricks.

Comment: Thanks @Bellerophon. Sorry, english is not my main language.